# List files in unix in a specific format to a text file

Tags: linux, unix

I want to list files in a particular folder to a file list but in a particular format

for instance i have below files in a folder

`/path/file1.csv`
`/path/file2.csv`
`/path/file3.csv`

I want to create a string in a text file that lists them as below

`-a file1.csv -a file2.csv -a file3.csv`

assist create a script for that

`ls /path/* > file_list.lst`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` utility can do this.

```
find /path/ -type f -printf "-a %P " > file_list.lst
```

This gives, for each thing that is a `f`ile in the given path (recursively), their `P`ath relative to the starting point, formatted as in your example.

Note that:

- Linux filenames can contain spaces and newlines; this does not deal with those.
- The `file_list.lst` file will have a trailing space but no trailing newline.
- The results will not be in a particular order.

Answer (score 2):

You can just `printf` them.

```
printf "-a %s " /path/*
```

If you plan to be using it with a command, you may want to read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 and interest yourself with `%q` printf format specifier.